# Geocoding from App Engine servers results in 620

Tags: google-app-engine, google-maps

Is anyone else having this problem?  Sometime last night after app engine's server maintenance, i have only successfully been able to geocode a few addresses -- most responses are 620 errors.  ive been running the same app with no problems for 3 months, so i think i think its a problem on google's end.  one other person on the google groups discussion was able to confirm, but i want to be sure because im very skeptical given that more people arent complaining.

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GGeoStatusCode.G_GEO_TOO_MANY_QUERIES)'s the explaination of the 620 status code.

"The given key has gone over the requests limit in the 24 hour period or has submitted too many requests in too short a period of time. If you're sending multiple requests in parallel or in a tight loop, use a timer or pause in your code to make sure you don't send the requests too quickly."

And a [post](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API/browse_thread/thread/b6e09c87527c1f26?pli=1) on the subject.

Hope it help!